# wso2 IS custom federated authenticator not showing in list

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have tried the custom federated authenticator sample given in wso2 doumentation(https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/authenticators/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sample.federated.authenticator), after building I have deployed in `/repository/components/dropins` folder. But after deployment it is not showing in the federated authenticator list. I am using wso2 IS 5.10.0

[image]

Below is the build which I used from the sample,

https://github.com/VIKRAMAS/wso2-custom-federated-authentor

But I tried to deploy github authenticator from IS connector store page, but it is working and showing in the federated authenticator list, but it is not working for the sample which I have deployed. But same build works in `wso2 IS version 5.12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is not activating (In INSTALLED state) in the IS5.10.0 pack due to the following issue. [image]

It may have a dependency on the application authentication framework, and you have specified the range as version 5.18.0 or above. But, 5.17.5 is the framework version available in runtime.

Check the framework version range in the pom file and correct it to a version range that contains 5.17.5 . Check the framework version range used for `<Import-Package>` in

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId> 
<plugin>
```

If the framework component is not defined with a range inside `<Import-Package>`, and  `<DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>` is used the runtime versions will be resolved dynamically. It takes the version range based on the framework version defined for dependencies (normally used for compilation).
eg: If the framework version is 5.18.21, it searches 5.18.0 - 6.0.0 version in runtime.

---

You can refer to **Useful OSGi commands to debug** section of https://anuradha-15.medium.com/lets-write-and-run-your-first-osgi-service-on-wso2-platform-482f6e5e3ea5 to learn more about OSGi activation issue trouble shooting.

Comment: yeah thank you the sample is supporting newer version of wso2.